# Instrumentation amplifier AD8293G160 - Why RC filter calculations don't match?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, adc, filter, instrumentation-amplifier

I am using an [AD8293G160](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8293G80_160.pdf) to handle a signal, for a known bandwidth.
The part is an INA with a fixed internal gain of 160x. It has 2 outputs, one direct, the other with an integrated 5k resistor to simplify antialiasing filters for ADC connections, see figure:

[image]

The DS explain, as an example, that to have a bandwidth of 500Hz, we need to combine the 2 filters using C3 = 39nF and C2 = 680pF. It says that the combination of 320k/680p give a 700Hz (correct), and the combination of another at 700Hz from 5k/39nF (but seems not correct).

Now I have 2 specific questions:

1. The 5k/39n combination is at 800Hz, is this a mistake? I followed the formula in the datasheet.
2. Once understood 1., how the comination can be an equivalent of 500Hz?

Bonus question is this:

I don't get the correct parts numbering differences. What changes from one or another, given the same 160x gain part? See image, there are 6 different model numbers, also at different prices if you check on a random distributor:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the result for both filters using a simulator: -

[image]

The blue trace is just the 320 kΩ resistor and 680 pF capacitor. The red trace is the same filter but with the 5 kΩ and 39 pF filter buffered on the back of it: -

[image]

So, Vout1 has a 3.01 dB point at 731.360 Hz and Vout2 has a 3.01 dB point at 496.177 Hz. Vout1 is a single order low-pass filter and Vout2 is a second order low-pass filter.

> *The 5k/39n combination is at 800Hz, is this a mistake? I followed the
> formula in the datasheet.*

Sure, if you did the math on the 5k // 39 nF filter it's more like 800 Hz but, the important thing here is that the combination is close to 500 Hz. Bigger picture of the bode plot: -

[image]

As you should be able to tell, the slope of the combined filter (second order) is twice that of the single order filter and will provide significantly improved anti-aliasing.

> *Bonus question*

The different part numbers relate to the quantities in which you can [purchase those items](https://www.analog.com/media/en/package-pcb-resources/tape-and-reel-packaging.pdf): -

- R7 is a 7 inch reel
- REEL is a 14 inch reel

Comment: Thanks. I'll go through the math in a moment. In the meantime, what is the difference between the A and B in the part numbers? Seems related to the "marking" label, and that really makes a difference in prices

Comment: Table 2 in the data sheet is for the A grade version. Table 3 is for the B grade version @thexeno - the B grade is better than the A grade.

Comment: Ah yes I understand. It is at 500 Hz since it is adding a pole to a previously present pole. But it is also different that using a second order filter in one RC combination, since there is a buffer in between. Is there a specific name for this topology? I wanted to look up some theory to find a formula to get the 500Hz - I assume it should be a basic concept, as it is 700/sqrt(2)

Comment: @thexeno In effect, the chip **does** buffer the two filters. The 680 pF filter is part of a feedback network hence, the output (prior to the next filter) acts as a buffer to that 680 pF filter. Then, added on the end is the 39 nF filter i.e. it is **truly** buffered from the 680 pF filter. To rationalize two identical filters that are buffered from each other (as in the case of the IC used) you need to derive the 1st order gain formula and find the frequency where the gain is 1.505 dB down. Then, cascading two or them produces a gain that is 3.01 dB down at that same frequency.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Also, somehow I did not see the A/B table in the datahseet I had before posting the question - apology for the idiocrazy. On the filter, I am just worried that they specify everything around 500Hz, and nothing at 10kHz or more, where I want to make the filter. But the 10kHz is in the graphs, so it should work, but I don't see an obvious bandwidth parameter around, am I fooling myself?

Comment: Well, all I can say is scale down the capacitors (680 pF and 39 nF) by the same amount so that you get something like the right values to give you a 10 kHz BW. However, I have strong suspicions that this device just isn't man enough to deliver decent performance at 10 kHz and, if you bench-tested it you might find that without any capacitors, it only just manages a 10 kHz BW.

Comment: Are we done now @thexeno ? I don't think I can contribute more to answering your original question.

Comment: Yes, thank you.